# Allow multiple Instances for AzureB2C

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We need to change the Instance-URL (so the user sees another URL) for our AzureB2C. Because the client is an App that still could have the old configuration we do not simply want to replace the instance configuration but allow both for a while.

This is our Approach. Config:

```
"AzureAdB2COld:ClientId": "GUID0",
"AzureAdB2COld:Domain":"ourdomain.onmicrosoft.com",
"AzureAdB2COld:Instance":"https://login.olddomain.com",
"AzureAdB2COld:SignUpSignInPolicyId":"B2C_1A_signin"
"AzureAdB2COld:TokenValidationParameters:ValidAudiences:0":"GUID1" ,
"AzureAdB2COld:TokenValidationParameters:ValidAudiences:1":"GUID2" 
    
"AzureAdB2CNew:ClientId": "GUID0",
"AzureAdB2CNew:Domain":"ourdomain.onmicrosoft.com",
"AzureAdB2CNew:Instance":"https://login.newdomain.com",
"AzureAdB2CNew:SignUpSignInPolicyId":"B2C_1A_signin"
"AzureAdB2CNew:TokenValidationParameters:ValidAudiences:0":"GUID1" ,
"AzureAdB2CNew:TokenValidationParameters:ValidAudiences:1":"GUID2"
```

(as you can see, only the "Instance"-Parameter is different)
We Configure this in Startup by adding two Authentications to the services:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
{
    Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2COld", options);
    options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "email";
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
    {
        OnTokenValidated = async (context) =>
        {
            var principalService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<PrincipalService>();
            await principalService.InitAsync(context.Principal);
        }
    };
},
options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2COld", options); }
);

services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
{
    Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2CNew", options);
    options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "email";
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
    {
        OnTokenValidated = async (context) =>
        {
            var principalService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<PrincipalService>();
            await principalService.InitAsync(context.Principal);
        }
    };
},
options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2CNew", options); }
);
```

While each of the configurations alone work fine, we get an error if we try to add both:

> InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Bearer
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationOptions.AddScheme(string name, Action configureBuilder)

Is there a way to allow both Instances through configuration at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

To make the code work is relativly simple. The second `AddAuthentication()` should not have a default scheme (there is only one default) and `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(..., ..., "AzureAdB2CNew")` should be named.

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
{
    Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2COld", options);
    options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "email";
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
    {
        OnTokenValidated = async (context) =>
        {
            var principalService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<PrincipalService>();
            await principalService.InitAsync(context.Principal);
        }
    };
},
options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2COld", options); }
);

services.AddAuthentication() 
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
{
    Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2CNew", options);
    options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "email";
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
    {
        OnTokenValidated = async (context) =>
        {
            var principalService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<PrincipalService>();
            await principalService.InitAsync(context.Principal);
        }
    };
},
options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2CNew", options); }, "AzureAdB2CNew"
);
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/688165/multiple-authentication-schemes-azure-ad-and-azure

To add multiple authorization reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-7.0#use-multiple-authentication-schemes.

Now for the bad news, as I’m having a similar issue with an Azure B2B client having tokens generated with two different instances. Because the client ID is the same, tokens generated with the old instance `https://login.olddomain.com` and the new instance `https://login.newdomain.com` will NOT be treated as different by the authentication code. The first instantiated authentication will consider either token a match based on the tokens audience `"aud":` (client id) but it will pass/fail validation based on the issuer `"iss":` (instance) matching.  When it fails you will receive the following error that blames the audience, but in truth should blame the issuer (instance).

```
401 Error: response status is 401

Response headers
 date: Fri,10 Mar 2023 20:08:03 GMT 
 server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 
 www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token",error_description="The audience 'fdf045d9-e73f-4fc4-99b9-b1e13a23da0d' is invalid",Bearer error="invalid_token",error_description="The issuer '(null)' is invalid" 
 x-powered-by: ASP.NET
```

I’m still looking for a solution to this problem. Since there seems to not be a good code solution short of writing a `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationBuilder` extension method to replace `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi`, I’m considering defining two different clients in Azure B2C, one for each instance.